# Adding CSS to this and a child in LESS?

Tags: css, less

Targeting children in LESS is easy such as:

```
header {
    a { color: white; }
}
```

But what I'm asking is how to assign `color: white;` to both the parent and the child? I can do:

```
header {
    color: white;
    a { color: white; }
}
```

But that is adding the same thing twice and I'm sure there's a better way in LESS.

Comment: Not when you're using it to override colors already assigned using higher specificity. Such as a in this case.

Comment: @torazburo That's true, but this is just an example. Other properties may not be inherited.

Comment: @torazaburo You're probably treating the examle too literally. Usually we use minimalistic simplified examples just to represent the problem. And an actual code may have nothing to do with `header`, `a` or `color`. Besides, in this particual case, the `a` element actually [*do not inherit*](http://codepen.io/seven-phases-max/pen/XdqyQB) color property of its parent tags (as it's already have implicit `user agent` assigned color).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want nesting there, then:

```
header {
    &, a {color: white}
}
```

For more details see [Parent Selectors](http://lesscss.org/features/#parent-selectors-feature).

Comment: Wouldn't it be `&, a`? It's already nested so it shouldn't have to be `&, & a`, right?

Comment: Yes, my mistake - fixed.